# Accessing (SSH and Ping) clients between two routers' networks

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I have two TP-Link Archer C1200 routers, both with different network ranges, and one of them is connected to the ISP's internet and the other is connected with the first using dynamic IP. I want to be able to SSH and ping (ICMP) the clients of one router network to another. Here is the configuration I set:

**Router-A config:**

- Internet (WAN Port): PPPoE (ISP's Internet)
- LAN: 192.168.0.1 with DHCP Server (reserved IP (192.168.0.5) is added
  for Router-B)
- Static Routing Entry: Net-Dest.: 192.168.200.0, Mask: 255.255.255.0,
  Gateway: 192.168.0.5, and Interface: LAN
- SPI Firewall: On
- Connected LAN Devices:
  client-A1: 192.168.0.10 (IP reserved and given by Router-A)

**Router-B config:**

- Internet (WAN Port): Dynamic IP (192.168.0.5 fetched from LAN port of
  Router-A )
- LAN: 192.168.200.1 with DHCP Server
- Port Forwarding (VS): External-Port: 22, Internal-IP: 192.168.200.12,
  Interna-Port: 22 (TCP)
- Port Forwarding (VS): External-Port: 7, Internal-IP: 192.168.200.12,
  Internal-Port: 7, (TCP & UDP)
- SPI Firewall: Off
- Remote Management: Enabled for All Devices
- Connected LAN Devices:
  client-B1: 192.168.200.12 (IP reserved and given by Router-B)
  client-B2: 192.168.200.14 (IP reserved and given by Router-B)

**My questions - How to be able to do the following:**

- From client-A1 I want to be able to SSH and Ping client-B1 and B2
- From client-A1 I want to be able to SSH and Ping the local address of
  Router-B1 (192.168.200.1), the remote management allows me only to do
  that with the WAN address (192.168.0.5)

Please let me know how to do it with the current IP configuration of both networks, or at least let me know what I set wrong. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: do you actually WANT two networks? would having the devices in a single network be better?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: I agree it will be easier if they are in one network but the issue is with the devices I bring from work (i.e., devices in Router-B), they came configured with a specific network range, which is different from a batch of devices to another. Thus, configuring these devices on my home network (as one) and then reconfiguring them back when returned to work will be a lot of effort. It will be easier if I put them within router-B and then just change the Router-B configuration to suit them. Besides, I really want to know how to do this regardless of what I said

Comment: Your configuration looks okay (and the port-forwarding rules should be completely unnecessary if you can get routing to work) – have you tried checking with `traceroute` if Router 1 at least forwards the packets to Router 2 (instead of sending them through WAN)?

Comment: I did traceroute as you suggested, and it seems Router-A does not forward the packets to Router-B but sends them to the ISP gateway. See the snapshot of traceroute and the static route configuration of Router-A in the below link.

https://i.imgur.com/053xJFY.png

what do you the issue is?